# date picker localization: override only language specific values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I found a demo of french date picker at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization
But i need only language specific change when I use  french locale.

So I have not taken

```
    weekHeader: 'Sem.',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''
```

to my french version from
http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js

So my french file is like only below

```
/* French initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Written by Keith Wood (kbwood{at}iinet.com.au) and Stéphane Nahmani (sholby@sholby.net). */
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
        closeText: 'Fermer',
        prevText: '&#x3c;Préc',
        nextText: 'Suiv&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
         monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
                       'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'], 
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun',
        'Jul','Aou','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
        dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dim','Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Di','Lu','Ma','Me','Je','Ve','Sa'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm'
        };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
});
```

So my question is,

Do other values like dateFormat takes from default file?

Added:

If I need only above values to be taken form this file and all other values to be taken from the default file,what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Nope that will be taken care by the **`jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js`** not the default datepicker.js.

From [Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

> 1. Datepicker provides support for localizing its content to cater for different languages and **date formats**.
> 2. *Each localization file adds its settings to the set of available localizations and automatically applies them as defaults for all
>      instances.*

**To make my comments clear**

Instead of adding the new locale file, make use of default options like below

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    closeText: 'Fermer',
        prevText: '&#x3c;Préc',
        nextText: 'Suiv&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
         monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
                       'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'], 
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun',
        'Jul','Aou','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
        dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dim','Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Di','Lu','Ma','Me','Je','Ve','Sa'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm'
});
```

> If I need only above values to be taken form this file and all other
>   values to be taken from the default file,what can i do?

Override the `$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);` to default like

```
$( '#date' ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
```

Comment: If I need only above values to be taken form this file and all other values to be taken from the default file,what can i do?

Comment: @user444569 Instead of adding this function that add these attributes to your default datepicker directly.

Comment: " add these attributes to your default datepicker directly" means?